# Confused about parameters for bool function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, function-pointers, heapsort

I am trying to call my heapify function which is supposed to create a binary tree and heap sort it in a way all depending on my boolean function parameter.

My problem: I am not sure how to pass the function pointer in main when calling my heapify function.

My attempt in passing the values along with my code is down below (I get an error when trying to call the function: expression must be an lvalue or a function designator)

```
struct S {
    double x;
    int n;
    char c;
};

void heapify(S bt[], unsigned els, bool(*shouldBeBefore)(const S & a, const S & b));

int main() {
    S test[9] = { {1.1,1,'A'},{1.3,2,'B'},{1.8,3,'C'},{1.7,4,'D'},{5.1,5,'E'},{4.3,6,'F'},{3.8,7,'G'},{4.7,8,'H'},{2.7,9,'I'} };
    heapify(x, 9,&shouldBeBefore(test[0], test[1]));
    return 0;
}

bool shouldBeBefore(const S & a, const S & b) {
    if (a.x < b.x) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your declaration (or entire definition) of `shouldBeBefore` above `main` where you invoke `heapify`.  But when you invoke `heapify`, you just pass in the function name.  `heapify` will invoke your `shouldBeBefore` function with it's own parameters.

```
void heapify(S bt[], unsigned els, bool(*shouldBeBefore)(const S & a, const S & b));
bool shouldBeBefore(const S & a, const S & b);

int main()
{
    S test[9] = { {1.1,1,'A'},{1.3,2,'B'},{1.8,3,'C'},{1.7,4,'D'},{5.1,5,'E'},
                  {4.3,6,'F'},{3.8,7,'G'},{4.7,8,'H'},{2.7,9,'I'} };

    unsigned int length = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]); // 9

    heapify(S, length, shouldBeBefore);

    return 0;
}

bool shouldBeBefore(const S & a, const S & b) 
{
    return (a.x < b.x);
}
```

In your implementation of `heapify`, you can invoke `shouldBeBefore` just like any other function:

```
void heapify(S bt[], unsigned els, bool(*shouldBeBefore)(const S & a, const S & b))
{
    ...
        if (shouldBeBefore(S[i+1], S[i]) {
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, I just wanted to clear an assumed confusion about the function pointer and the function.

```
void heapify(S bt[], unsigned els, bool(*shouldBeBefore)(const S & a, const S & b));

int main() {
    [...]
    heapify(x, 9, shouldBeBefore(test[0], test[1]));
    [...]
}

bool shouldBeBefore(const S & a, const S & b) {
    return a.x < b.x;
}
```

`shouldBeBefore` names the function as well as the function argument. This adds some confusion. `heapify` is actually allowed to take any function with signature `bool(const S&, const S&)`, and the name should suggest so.

For function pointers, it is always handy to add a type definition

```
using Comparator = bool(*)(const S&, const S&);
// typedef bool(*Comparator)(const S&, const S&); // or by typedef
```

The code would then look like

```
void heapify(S bt[], unsigned els, Comparator comparator);

int main() {
    [...]
    heapify(x, 9, shouldBeBefore(test[0], test[1]));
    [...]
}

bool shouldBeBefore(const S & a, const S & b) {
    return a.x < b.x;
}
```

and you call comparator as you would any other function.

Defining function pointer is a bit verbose. You can also use std::function, which would give a slighty easier syntax

```
using Comparator = std::function<bool(const S&, const S&>>;
```

Advantage is that you can call heapify with any callable.